# Should we break down the iOS documentation?

Tags: discussion, documentation, documentation-topics

As I look through the iOS documentation, it seems a little cluttered. There are topics on [Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/434/passing-data-between-view-controllers#t=201611291810070339423), [Anything](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/1409/uiimage) [you](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/874/uialertcontroller) [can](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/695/uiimageview) [imagine](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/246/uilabel) [from UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/956/uicolor), [Core Location](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/2937/core-location#t=2016112918143058319) and there are even ones on [`NSDate`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/1502/nsdate) and [`NSTimer`](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/ios/2624/nstimer).

Should we create documentation for `UIKit`, `CoreLocation` and all the other frameworks, would it be better to add sub-catergories for each of the iOS frameworks, or is it good as is?

Comment: So, you might be fighting an uphill battle. Similar to the DOM and JavaScript, or .NET and C#, because people conflate the framework with the language or platform they are most commonly written on/in, people will complain if they don't see something about Core Location in iOS, even though it's over on, say, a [`core-location` tag](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/core-location).